# How to open utf 16 Big Endian text file in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to open and convert text files of all encoding types on my notepad project.

I got successfully text data from all files of types except utf 16 big endian.

Here is my code of operation File::Load() :

```
#include "File.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

/* skip other codes */

string File::Load() {
    string content = "";
    string mode = "";
    int encode;
    string type;

    FILE *file;
    fopen_s(&file, this->name.c_str(), "rb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        encode = fgetc(file);
        if (encode == 254) {
            type = "BE";
            mode = "rt";
        }
        else if (encode == 255) {
            type = "LE";
            mode = "rt, ccs=UTF-16LE";
        }
        else if (encode == 239) {
            type = "UTF8 BOM";
            mode = "rt, ccs=UTF-8";
        }
        else if (encode > 200) {
            type = "UTF8";
            mode = "rt, ccs=UTF-8";
        }
        else {
            type = "ANSI";
            mode = "rt";
        }
        fclose(file);
    }

    char (*line) = new char[99999];
    wchar_t (*wLine) = new wchar_t[99999];
    string str;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ko-KR");
    if (fopen_s(&file, this->name.c_str(), mode.c_str()) == 0) {
        while (!feof(file)) {
            if (type == "BE") {
                fgetws(wLine, 99998, file);
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wLine, -1, line, 99999, NULL, NULL);
            }
            else if (type == "LE") {
                fgetws(wLine, 99998, file);
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wLine, -1, line, 99999, NULL, NULL);
            }
            else if (type == "UTF8 BOM") {
                fgetws(wLine, 99998, file);
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wLine, -1, line, 99999, NULL, NULL);
            }
            else if (type == "UTF8") {
                fgetws(wLine, 99998, file);
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wLine, -1, line, 99999, NULL, NULL);
            }
            else if (type == "ANSI") {
                fgets(line, 99998, file);
            }

            str = string(line);
            if (str.at(str.length() - 1) == '\n') {
                str = str.substr(0, str.length() - 1);
            }
            content += str + "\r\n";
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    content = content.substr(0, content.length() - 2);

    if (line != 0) {
        delete[] line;
    }
    if (wLine != 0) {
        delete[] wLine;
    }

    return content;
}
```

In my case, the problem is open mode for utf 16 big endian.

I tried every ccs flags written in msdn.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019

Like this :

```
if (encode == 254) {
    type = "BE";
    mode = "rt";
    //1.// mode = "rt, ccs=UNICODE";
    //2.// mode = "rt, ccs=UTF-16LE";
    //3.// mode = "rt, ccs=UTF-8";
}
```

But fopen_s function causes error like this image in every 'mode' i tried.
[image]

If i open file by just "rt", multibyte characters are broken.

how can i open and convert utf 16 big endian text file?

Thanks for your help.

Additional question :

I also wanna know how to set various locales at the same time.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ko-KR");
```

App cannot read correctly specific languages like Arabian.

I am working on Windows 10, VS2019.

Comment: You should be always reading bytes from the file as `char`, and then swapping the byte order if the endianness does not match your system.  The type `wchar_t` is not guaranteed to be 2 bytes, so you should not rely on that either.

Comment: Also check out [Using Byte Order Marks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-byte-order-marks) if you haven't read that yet.

Comment: Why are you tagging C if it's C++?

Comment: @klutt because FILE structure and fopen function is C style.

Comment: @paddy i don't understand you saying that swapping the byte order. please give me more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: To convert the byte order from big-endian to little endian.  For example, if you have an array `char arr[N];` containing bytes read in from a file encoded as UTF-16 big-endian, you can convert it to UTF-16 little-endian with something like `for (int i = 1; i < N; i += 2) std::swap(arr[i], arr[i-1]);` -- then you can call `WideCharToMultiByte`

Comment: That's a Windows question rather than a C or C++ question. Just sayin',

Comment: @paddy I got your word as I should change encoding method of file by swapping the byte order of all text data. Am i right?

Comment: No, you should not change the file's encoding.  That would involve rewriting the file.  I'm saying that the Windows API function you're calling does not understand big-endian encoding, so you must change the encoding to little-endian (by swapping the byte order) _IN MEMORY_.

Comment: @paddy "*The type `wchar_t` is not guaranteed to be 2 bytes*" - that may be true *in general*, but on Windows *specifically*, it is guaranteed. Every Windows compiler implements `wchar_t` as 2 bytes, because that is what the Win32 API requires since the `WCHAR` type is defined as an alias for 2-byte `wchar_t` for handling UTF-16 encoded strings.